# Convert a non exact differential equation into an exact differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given equation is
$$ \left ( 3y^{2}-7x^{2}+7\right)x\mathrm dx + \left ( 7y^{2}-3x^{2}+3\right )y\mathrm dy=0$$
Here $\frac{\partial M}{\partial y} \neq \frac{\partial N}{\partial x}$ so it is not a exact differential equation. I want to covert this equation into exact differential equation. For that i need to find out Integrating Factor (IF). Please suggest me how i can find IF for this equation.

Comment: This is not an equation. Where is the `=` sign?

Answer (score 2):

Hint : You could rewrite it as
\begin{eqnarray*}
(3y^2-7(x^2-1))d(x^2-1)+(7y^2-3(x^2-1))d(y^2)
\end{eqnarray*}
or
\begin{eqnarray*}
(3Y-7X)dX+(7Y-3X)dY.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanx now it is easy to solve. However, still it is not exact differential equation.

Comment: Integrating factor: $\mu=\frac{1}{(y^2-x^2+1)(y^2+x^2-1)}$
Answer: $(y^2-x^2+1)^2(y^2+x^2-1)^5=C$

Answer (score 1):

$$\left ( 3y^{2}-7x^{2}+7\right)xdx + \left ( 7y^{2}-3x^{2}+3\right )ydy=0$$
$$\left ( 3y^{2}-7x^{2}+7\right)dx^2 =-\left ( 7y^{2}-3x^{2}+3\right )dy^2$$
$$\dfrac {dx^2}{( 7y^{2}-3x^{2}+3)}=-\dfrac {dy^2}{ 3y^{2}-7x^{2}+7}$$
$$\dfrac {d(x^2-y^2)}{5(y^2-x^2+1)}=\dfrac {d(x^2+y^2)}{2(x^2+y^2-1)}$$
$$\dfrac {dv}{5v}+\dfrac {du}{2u}=0$$
Where $v=x^2-y^2-1$ and $u=x^2+y^2-1$

The differential equation is now exact and you can easily integrate it .

Comment: Yes, thanking you @Aryadeva

Comment: you're welcomed @shoyabkhan